# When to use Partial derivatives and chain rule

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

This might be a better way to ask the question.

I have a function $f(x,y)=2x+3y$ where $x=x(s,t), y=y(s,t)$.

Then some people tell me that,

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}$.

The definition of the total derivative with respect to $s$ is

$\frac{df}{ds}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}$.

This implies, using the partial derivative result above, that

$\frac{df}{ds}=2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + 2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}$.

This (the total derivative is 2 times the partial derivative) seems wrong to me.  I know the total derivative equation is correct.  This means the partial derivative above is wrong.

Can someone please help me understand what the correct partial derivative result should be.  Thanks!

---

Original question:

I have a function $f(x,y)=2x+3y$ and I am told to take the partial derivative with respect to $s$.   My answer is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}=0$.

But then I am told that $x=x(s,t), y=y(s,t)$ and asked if it makes any difference to my answer above.  My answer is: No, it makes no difference.  The partial of $f$ with respect to $s$ is still zero.

I am told that I am wrong.  Why?   I thought that the partial derivative was obtained by "holding all other parameters constant and vary $s$."  But if I hold $x$ and $y$ constant, then the result is zero, right?

Someone told me that I have to use the chain rule for partial derivatives in this case.  How?

I see for the total derivative, I would have
$\frac{df}{ds}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}$

and this uses the partial derivative chain rule.  But the partial derivative of $f$ would not.

Am I correct that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}=0$ when $f(x,y)=2x+3y$ and $x=x(s,t), y=y(s,t)$?

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ depend on $s$ (which should be indicated by writing $x(s)$ and $y(s)$ to avoid misunderstandings), the partial derivate with respect to $s$ is in fact not $0$, although $s$ does not appear explicitely. The rule you mentioned is correct if the unknowns are independent. If $x$ and $y$ do not depend on $s$; then of course $f(x,y)$ has derivate $0$ with respect to $s$

Comment: In your equation for the total derivative, the same letter $f$ is being used to denote two different functions. This is a common abuse of notation but it can cause confusion.

Comment: Can you provide more detail?  If $s$ does not appear explicitly, and "all other parameters are held constant", even if they depend on $s$, so the partial with respect to $s$ is zero.  But you say that is not correct?  So $x(s,t)$ is not held constant?  Can you provide rule/formula?

Comment: If $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, I prefer the notation $D_1 f$ for the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its first input and $D_2 f$ for the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its second input. For the function $f(x,y) = 2x + 3y$, it's unclear what "partial derivative with respect to $s$" even means.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that 
$$F(s,t) = f(x(s,t),y(s,t))$$ 
for all $s, t \in \mathbb R$.  (Here $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, x:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ , and $y:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ are differentiable functions.)
Then the chain rule tells us that
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial s} =
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}
+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}.
$$
The notation here might be slightly confusing because the inputs to the functions $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}$, etc, have been suppressed.  It might be more clear to write the inputs to these functions explicitly.  In fact, if there is any confusion, I sometimes think it is most clear to write the chain rule using the following notation:
$$
D_1F(s,t) = D_1f(x(s,t),y(s,t)) D_1x(s,t) + D_2f(x(s,t),y(s,t)) D_1y(s,t)
$$
for all $s,t \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks, littleO!  I think it is starting to make sense.  I can understand that the notation commonly used is confusing.  Looks like you are evaluating $\frac{\partial F}{\partial s}$ whereas I specifically need to understand $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}$.  I see these are different functions.  Their domains are different, for example.  And $\frac{\partial F}{\partial s} = \frac{d f}{d s}$ as well as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}=0$.

Comment: One thing that I dislike about the notation $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ is that it's unclear why we are using the letter $x$.  Sure, maybe when we were defining $g$ we used the letter $x$, like $g(x) = \sin(x^2)$, but that was an arbitrary choice and we could have equally well used a different letter.  We could have defined $g$ by saying $g(w) = \sin(w^2)$ or $g(v) = \sin(v^2)$.  So why is the letter $x$ used to denote the first partial derivative of $g$?  It would be more clear to denote the first partial derivative of $g$ as $D_1 g$.  What do you mean by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}$?

Comment: What I mean by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}$ is the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to a variable that is not an explicit parameter of $f$.  And this is why $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s} = 0$  when $s$ is not an explicit parameter of $f$.  Example: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial }{\partial s}(6x+7y)=0$.  $s$ does not occur in $6x+7y$ so the partial derivative of $6x+7y$ with respect to $s$ is zero, regardless of whether or not $x$ and $y$ are functions of $s$.  In your notation $D_3 f(x,y)=0$. There is no 3rd parameter.